# Why does omitting explicit 'int' type for a parameter fail to compile in gcc sometimes?

Tags: c, gcc

When declaring variables in C you can omit the type sometimes if you want to declare an `int`.

Why does omitting explicit 'int' type for a parameter fail to compile in gcc with other non-int parameters, unless declared in the K&R style?

This code generates an error:

```
main(argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* . . . */
}
```

With the following output:

```
$gcc XXX.c -oXXX
XXX.c:X:X: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
 main(argc, char *argv[])
            ^
```

However, if I write K&R style types for the parameters I can omit specifying an `int` type for the first parameter:

```
main(argc, argv)
char *argv[];
{
  /* . . . */
}
```

And that compiles fine.

I suspect the reason is that when making the first C standard they decided that the K&R automatic-int notation should be completely seperate from the newer syntax for function parameters, especially since by the time the standard was being pulled together the automatic-int notation was likely already considered poor notation.

My interest in these rules is academic, I don't generally write this old-style C.

Comment: because you should not be doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two forms of function definition in C: K&R style and the modern style with prototypes. You cannot mix them in a single definition.

In K&R style (i.e., the style used in the 1978 first edition of Kernighan & Ritchie's "The C Programming Language", published 11 years before the first official ANSI standard for the language), you could write:

```
/* Valid in K&R and 1989 ANSI C, invalid in C99 and later */
main(argc, argv)    
char *argv[];
{
    /* . . . */
}
```

The stuff between the parentheses can *only* be a (possibly empty) sequence of identifiers, the names of the parameters. Between the `)` and `{` you could optionally have a sequence of parameter declarations, specifying their types. If you omitted the type of a parameter, or of the function itself, it would default to `int`.

The 1989 ANSI C standard kept this old form for backward compatibility, but declared it to be obsolescent. (Unfortunately, IMHO, it's remained that way even in the 2011 ISO C standard.)

The 1999 ISO C standard dropped the "implicit int" rule, so even if, for some odd reason, you wanted to use an old-style definition, you'd still have to give all the types explicitly:

```
 /* Valid in all versions of C, but obsolescent */
int main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    /* ... */
}
```

A modern prototype definition for `main` would be:

```
/* Valid in 1989 ANSI C and later; write it this way! */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    /* ... */
}
```

You should always use prototypes; there is no good reason to write an old-style function definition (unless you're stuck using a very old compiler, but it has become very difficult even to find such a compiler).

Comment: Thanks a lot, a more specific answer with some extra useful facts (like dropping implicit int in ISO 99). As I said before this is only of academic interest, the new prototype format is more consise and easier to read so I have no practical use for the old one at all.

Comment: In the second example, do I spy an extra, errant `{`?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is employing one of two grammars.

When applying the K&R grammar, undeclared parameters are allowed, and default to ints.

When applying the non-K&R grammar, all parameters must comply with the parameter declaration syntax i.e. declared with types and names.

You invoke one or the other by choosing the corresponding declaration style.