# why this program is not showing any error?

Tags: c

in the code below .

- i have defined function prototype with no argument
- in definition as well as in function call i have used one parameter.

i would like to know  why i am not getting any error ?

```
# include <stdio.h>
float circle();       /* no parameter*/
int main()
{
    float area;
    int radius =2;
    area=circle(radius);
    printf("%f \n",area);
    return 0;
}

float circle( r) /* with one parameter even no parameter type */
{
    float a;
    a=3.14*r*r;
    return (a);
}
```

Comment: Don't hardcode pi. Use M_PI from math.h. EDIT: Actually I don't think this is standard C. So check first.

Answer (score 4):

The

```
float circle();
```

is not a function with zero parameters. It's a function with an unspecified number of parameters.

The

```
float circle( r) {
```

is a K&R-style definition in which the type of `r` defaults to `int`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18433812/367273

Comment: Now the only question is if `float(int)` is the same as `float(...)` where `...` means unspecified number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This is because compiler treat `r` as `int` by default when no parameter is defined for `circle`. Try to run your code after declaring function prototype as

```
float circle(void);
```

and you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because function

```
float circle();
```

declaration doesn't declare function that takes no arguments.
It's implicitly declared as a function that takes undefined number of integer variables as arguments.
Just like

```
function();
```

is valid function declaration. Implicitly this function will be treated as function taking `int` as arguments and returning `int`. 
If you want to declare function function taking no arguments or not returning any value, you do it with `void` keyword:

```
void funct(void);
```